# i have no content on page after reloading in angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have an Angular 8 project with four components, one holds the router-outlet, and three working components. Application starts at `/`, then via navbar I switch the pages (other two have URLs like `/departments` and `/languages`, and after I update these two pages

[image: 1]

via <kbd>F5</kbd> or like that, i have

[image: 2]

If I back (via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> arrow on keyboard) I have same behavior. What's wrong?

root component:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <nav class="nav">
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="">Сотрудники</a>
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/departments">Отделы</a>
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/languages">Языки программирования</a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

example of `/languages` component:

```html
<h1>Языки программирования</h1>
<input type="button" value="Добавить" class="btn btn-default" (click)="add()" />
<table *ngIf="tableMode; else create" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Название</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let p of languages; trackBy: trackByLangID">
    <ng-template [ngIf]="language?.languageID != p.languageID" [ngIfElse]="edit">
      <td>{{p?.name}}</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="editLanguage(p)">Изменить/Сохранить</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="delete(p)">Удалить</button>
      </td>
    </ng-template>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

app.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { deptsComponent } from './departments/depts.component';
import { langsComponent } from "./languages/langs.component";
import { empsComponent } from "./employees/emps.component";
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {rootComponent} from "./root/main.component";
import {main} from "@angular/compiler-cli/src/main";

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: empsComponent},
  {path: 'departments', component: deptsComponent},
  {path: 'languages', component: langsComponent}
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule,FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule,RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  declarations: [deptsComponent,langsComponent, empsComponent,rootComponent],
  bootstrap: [rootComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

what DOM look like after reloading:
[image: 4]

network listener(only GET from backend server(ASP.NET Core)):
[image: 5]

Comment: Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. You provided only the HTML part, so other people could only guess about what happens.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'm kinda new to stackoverflow. Posted some additional screens

Comment: Please don't post your sources (`app.module.ts`) as images. See [_"DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: updated the summary

Comment: Is your angular app and backend API running on same port?

Comment: Backend API is listening ports 5000 and 5001, and frontend is sending requests to these two ports